# Middle align a sticky column

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to have a table with a sticky first column. The content in the sticky column is always in top of the probably because position is absolute.
How can I middle align the text in the sticky column?

```css
        table {
          border-collapse: separate;
          border-top: 3px solid grey;
        }
        
        td,
        th {
          margin: 0;
          border: 3px solid grey;
          border-top-width: 0px;
          height: 30px;
        }
        
        div {
          width: 600px;
          overflow-x: scroll;
          margin-left: 70px;
          overflow-y: visible;
          padding-bottom: 1px;
        }
        
        .stickycol {
          line-height: 13px;
          position: absolute;
          width: 70px;
          left: 0;
          top: auto;
          border-right: 0px none black;
          border-top-width: 3px;
          /*only relevant for first row*/
          margin-top: -3px;
          /*compensate for top border*/
          
          
          word-wrap: break-word;
           white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
          /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
          white-space: -pre-wrap;
          /* Opera 4-6 */
          white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
          /* Opera 7 */
          white-space: pre-wrap;
          /* css-3 */
          word-wrap: break-word;
          /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
          white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;
          /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
          word-break: break-all;
          white-space: normal;
        }
        
        .long {
          letter-spacing: 1em;
        }
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="stickycol">col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">This text is so long</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">2</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">3</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">4</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">5</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">6</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">7</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">8</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">9</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just add few css properties in the stickycol css class.

**align-items:center** and **display:flex** are for verically align

**justify-content** and **text-align** are for horizontally align.

see the snippet.

```css
   table {
          border-collapse: separate;
          border-top: 3px solid grey;
        }
        
        td,
        th {
          margin: 0;
          border: 3px solid grey;
          border-top-width: 0px;
          height: 30px;
        }
        
        div {
          width: 600px;
          overflow-x: scroll;
          margin-left: 70px;
          overflow-y: visible;
          padding-bottom: 1px;
        }
        
        .stickycol {
        text-align:center;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
        display:flex;
          line-height: 13px;
          position: absolute;
          width: 70px;
          left: 0;
          top: auto;
          border-right: 0px none black;
          border-top-width: 3px;
          /*only relevant for first row*/
          margin-top: -3px;
          /*compensate for top border*/
          
          
          word-wrap: break-word;
           white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;
          /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
          white-space: -pre-wrap;
          /* Opera 4-6 */
          white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
          /* Opera 7 */
          white-space: pre-wrap;
          /* css-3 */
          word-wrap: break-word;
          /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
          white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap;
          /* Newer versions of Chrome/Safari*/
          word-break: break-all;
          white-space: normal;
        }
        
        .long {
          letter-spacing: 1em;
        }
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="stickycol">col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">This text is so long</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">2</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">3</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">4</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">5</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">6</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">7</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">8</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="stickycol">9</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pawan Kumar :)